# Apache mod_rewrite variables in conditions

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to match a referer to a host name in my .htaccess and stumbled upon the following.

The condition reads:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://%{HTTP_HOST}.*$
```

But this never matches, and the log file for mod_rewrite states this:

```
RewriteCond: input='https://mysite.com/test.htm' pattern='^https://%{HTTP_HOST}.*$' => not-matched
```

Why is the HTTP_HOST variable not getting expanded in this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203058/variable-in-htaccess-rewriterule-question) and [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4167032.htm#msg4167034) for details / workarounds.

Comment: So it appears there is no way to work around my particular issue, where I want to substitute host name into the comparison?